# 3 inner joins and a left join in my FROM statement

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am debugging some code for an MS Access program with a SQL backend. One of the queries is producing the following error: "the expression on click you entered as the event property setting produced the following error:

> cannot join on Memo, OLE, or Hyperlink Object (master_export.item=vw_items.Item)"

This is the original code:

```
SELECT master_export_pt.commitment_number AS [Commitment Number], 
  Sum(master_export_pt.receipt_amount) AS Amount, 
  LocalLocation.Location_Name AS Child_Location_Name, 
  LocalLocation_1.Location_Name AS Parent_Location_Name, 
  BypassLocation.JNL_Sales AS ByPassSales, 
  BypassLocation.JNL_COGS AS ByPassCogs, 
  master_export_pt.order_type
FROM (((master_export_pt 
  INNER JOIN vw_items ON master_export_pt.item = vw_items.Item) 
  INNER JOIN BypassLocation ON master_export_pt.location_id = BypassLocation.location_id) 
  INNER JOIN LocalLocation ON BypassLocation.location_id = LocalLocation.Location_ID) 
  LEFT JOIN LocalLocation AS LocalLocation_1 
    ON LocalLocation.parent_location_id = LocalLocation_1.Location_ID
```

and tried changing the first JOIN to:

```
FROM (((master_export_pt, vw_items) 
  where (master_export_pt.item = vw_items.Item)) 
  INNER JOIN BypassLocation ON master_export_pt.location_id = BypassLocation.location_id) 
  INNER JOIN LocalLocation ON BypassLocation.location_id = LocalLocation.Location_ID) 
  LEFT JOIN LocalLocation AS LocalLocation_1 
    ON LocalLocation.parent_location_id = LocalLocation_1.Location_ID
```

but now i get the "Syntax error in JOIN operation" error message. Is there a way to re-write the query without using nested JOIN statements?

Comment: Pay attention to the location of the opening `(` and closing `)` in each pair.

Comment: Thank you Ken. Wasn't able to get a different outcome.

Comment: Are you unable to join on a primary key field whose data type is not one of Memo, Hyperlink or OLE object?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to all who responded. I tried the following code and it seems to have done the trick:

```
SELECT
  xxx.commitment_number AS [Commitment Number],
  Sum(xxx.receipt_amount) AS Amount,
  xxx.Location_Name AS Child_Location_Name,
  xxx.Location_Name AS Parent_Location_Name,
  xxx.JNL_Sales AS ByPassSales,
  xxx.JNL_COGS AS ByPassCogs,
  xxx.order_type
FROM (
SELECT * FROM
    master_export_pt AS mept, vw_items AS vi, BypassLocation AS bl, LocalLocation AS ll
WHERE mept.item = vi.Item
        AND mept.location_id = bl.location_id
        AND bl.location_id = ll.Location_ID) AS xxx
LEFT OUTER JOIN LocalLocation AS ll1 ON xxx.parent_location_id = ll1.Location_ID 
GROUP BY
  xxx.commitment_number,
  xxx.Location_Name,
  ll1.Location_Name,
  xxx.JNL_Sales,
  xxx.JNL_COGS,
  xxx.order_type;
```